# Only allow one instance of main activity

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a single activity wear application with singleInstance set as launchMode.
When I swipe right or put the palm over the watch, the application goes to the background (pause/stop), then when I tap on its icon it opens again (resume) but it shows a **new** main activity and **not the original one**. 
I would like the app to only have **1** main activity.

I did unsuccessfully try other values for the launchMode and I also unsuccessfully tried to set flags.

I do not post the code since it is just simple wear app with a TextView and a Button on the main activity. When the button is pressed a counter increases and updates the text. When the app resumes the counter shows zero as if the button was never pressed.

Comment: Android doesn't start multiple instances of one activity unless you tell it to do so, so it's probably just killing your app

Comment: Nope, it is not killing it! In fact the complete app is a socket client that vibrates when receives a message. When the app is not on the screen the watch still vibrates when the socket server sends a message. So I understand it is not killed!

Answer (score 2):

You lose your data since the old activity gets destroyed when going to the background and gets restored when coming back. This is the normal behavior.
When you want to keep your data, you need to save and restore it e.g. save in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks Jakob, I understand what you're saying. But do you mean to restore onResume? Isn't in fact onCreate just called once at the very beginning?

Comment: Only onCreate provides you the savedInstanceState Bundle. So this is the preferred place to restore anything from it. I'm pretty sure that onDestroy and onCreate are called in your case.

Comment: Yes Jakob, you're right! I just checked the logs when I swipe right and the following methods are called in order: onPause, onStop, onDestroy. As I wrote above to Markaos, my app is a socket client and when it is not visible on the screen it still vibrates when the server sends a message. I was thus assuming the activity was not destroyed at all! My problem now is that when it vibrates it also changes some elements of the UI, but when resumed nothing changes! As if there are two stacked activities and only the bottom one gets affected by the changes.

Comment: When you still receive data in your activity that is not visible, I guess you have a serious memory leak. Please check this: Open the Android monitor, start your activity for the first time, put you activity to the background and back again. Now hit Dump Java Heap in the memory monitor. Analyzer Tasks should now be in the top right corner. Check there if your activity gets leaked

Comment: Hello Jakob, I can't see any leak! https://s8.postimg.org/61yhnk1yt/heap.png Anyways I noticed that onSaveInstanceState doesn't get called when the app is sent to the background so when I check if savedInstanceState is null in onCreate it never finds a previous instance state. Thanks!

Comment: On the right at "Analysis Results" there is a leaked activity. Please make sure that you release all references to the activity before it gets destroyed so the garbage collector can do its work. Can you show the code of your activity? Would make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: You're right. The leak happens when I swipe right to remove the app from the screen (when I swipe onPause, onStop, onDestroy are called) https://s9.postimg.org/ce1lmfn1b/leak.png
Here's the code https://pastebin.com/iEB34tm9

Comment: Okay the problem is that you call methods from your activity directly in your AsyncTask. This means whenever you start your AsyncTask it holds a reference to the activity to make this possible. You either need to stop your AsyncTask when your activity stops. Or use a lifecycle aware component like a loader to do your background work.

Comment: Yes Jakob, that's correct! A reference was kept, I did try both your options and both stopped the leak. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Now you can try to save and restore your state

Comment: I've noticed different behaviors when "closing" the app: swiping right calls onPause, onStop, onDestroy while putting the palm over the screen calls onPause, onSaveInstanceState, onStop.